# gcc compiler instrumentation - extract parameters + return value

Tags: c++, c, gcc, instrumentation

If I have

```
void func(int a, char * c)
{
// Something
}
```

And want to instrument using the flag 
[-finstrument-functions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html)

> Generate instrumentation calls for entry and exit to functions. Just
>   after function entry and just before function exit, the following
>   profiling functions are called with the address of the current
>   function and its call site. (On some platforms,
>   __builtin_return_address does not work beyond the current function, so the call site information may not be available to the profiling
>   functions otherwise.)
>
> ```
> void __cyg_profile_func_enter (void *this_fn,
>                                      void *call_site);
> void __cyg_profile_func_exit  (void *this_fn,
>                                      void *call_site);
> ```

is it possible to obtain the parameters at the beginning and end of a function?

**UPDATE #1**

I'm fine just dumping the binary blob of each parameter and then reconstructing the object, integer, etc post-mortem.

Comment: A quick test with a few minimal functions suggests that this is *not* possible in general, and extraordinarily hacky in the cases where it *is* possible.

Comment: @EOF can you give example where it is not possible?

Comment: If the function doesn't use its parameters, and the calling conventions pass arguments in registers, the compiler will just overwrite the first two integer/pointer argument-registers with the arguments for `__cyg_profile_func_enter()` without saving the original arguments when optimizing.

Comment: @EOF that's not the kiss of death for me. Most of the time we do use our values. What else could go wrong?

Comment: If you *do* use all parameters in the original function, the compiler will have to save the arguments on the stack. Unfortunately, the compiler will likely do this at the same time as it is reserving stackspace for local variables for the function. The only way the `cyg_profile*()` functions can get at the arguments is through an offset from the stack-pointer after the call. Throw in required stack-alignment for good measure, and you have *no idea* what the offset will be. You'd need debug-info to find it.

Comment: Worse, in `__cyg_profile_func_exit()`, the values of the arguments are effectively meaningless unless it so happens that the function is tail-calling another function with the (possibly modified) arguments it was passed itself. Otherwise, the compiler is likely to reuse the stackspace it allocated for the argument for a local variable if the lifetime of the argument and the local variable do not overlap.

Comment: @EOF wouldn't that be a bug in `__cyg_profile_func_exit()` ?

Comment: I mean "the value of the arguments of the original function, accessed through the stackpointer in `__cyg_profile_func_exit()` at some offset you don't know" is meaningless. The arguments to `__cyg_profile_func_exit()` *itself* are presumably fine. Sorry for the questionably precise wording.

Comment: @EOF thanks. I also have a similar question regarding [getting sequence of events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39296202/gcc-gprof-gcov-other-how-to-get-sequence-of-function-calls-exits-control-flo)

Comment: @EOF is there any technical reason why GCC (or any other compiler) couldn't implement this?

Comment: Because sane people use debuggers for this kind of problem. Once you add two function call overheads plus whatever operation your hooks perform (logging? I/O?), you *really* don't have a performance advantage over running the whole program without optimizations in a debugger.

Comment: @EOF performance is not an issue for us. Can `gdb` trace and save to logs?

Comment: [Yes](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Process-Record-and-Replay.html#Process-Record-and-Replay), depending on your platform.

Comment: @EOF I found a guy [who implemented exactly what I need](http://linuxgazette.net/151/melinte.html). Is there anything wrong with his approach?

Comment: @EOF I want to avoid using `gdb` because we want to lump in integration testing into validation testing: testers testing production code with a runtime switch to enable/disable logging. Using `gdb` means we have to build with `-g` which is not production configuration.

Comment: @Bob Looks like this doesn't work with gcc 9: it stuffs the parameters on the bottom of the stack in the opposite order, and you don't know how large the new stack is, so you cannot determine which arg is #1! Any luck doing this on modern gcc?