# gcc gprof/gcov/other - how to get sequence of function calls/exits + control flow statements

Tags: c++, gcc, instrumentation, gcov, gprof

**BACKGROUND**

We have testers for our embedded GUI product and when a tester declares "test failed", sometimes it's hard for us developers to reproduce the exact problem because we don't have the exact trace of what happened.

We do currently have a logging framework but us devs have to manually input those logging statements in the code which is fine . . . except when a hard-to-reproduce bug occurs and we didn't have a log statement at the 'right' location and then when we re-build, re-run the test with the same steps, we get a different result.

**ISSUE**

We would like a solution wherein the compiler produces extra instrumentation code that allows us to see the exact **sequence** of events including, at the *minimum*:

1. function enter/exit (already provided by [`-finstrument-functions`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html))
2. control-flow statement enter i.e. entering if/else, which case statement we jumped to

The log would look like this:

```
int main() entered
if-line 5 entered
else-line 10 entered
void EventLoop() entered
. . .
```

Some additional nice-to-haves are

3. Parameter values on function entry **AND** exit (for pass-by-reference types)
4. Function return value

**QUESTION**

Are there any `gcc` tools or even paid tools that can do this instrumentation automatically?

Comment: It sounds like you need a debugger.

Comment: @EOF we have a debugger. A debugger won't record the complete call trace. But even if it does, we want ability to trace without debugger

Comment: Unless you have a lot of tail-call optimizations, a stacktrace should give you the required sequence of calls. Maybe you can have the testers cause a coredump by sending an appropriate signal?

Comment: @EOF will that maintain a running list? Or once the stack unwinds will that info disappear?

Comment: @EOF I'm basically looking for a builtin logging facility.

Comment: I don't think you're going to get it in compiled code, because the output will be voluminous and it will slow the program way down. What we do is ask the user to send us the input that causes the problem, and specific instructions how to reproduce it.

Comment: You can try out the [uftrace](https://github.com/namhyung/uftrace) which is supported for ARM platform also.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use gdb for that, and you can automate that (I've got a tool for that in the works, you find it [here](https://github.com/mw-sc/mw.gdb-runner) or you can try to use gcov.

The gcov implementation is so, that it loads the latest gcov data when you start the program. But: you can manually dump and load the data. If you call `__gcov_flush` it will dump the current data and reset the current state. However: if you do that several times it will always merge the data, so you'd also need to rename the gcov data file then.

Comment: Does this require the tester to interact with gdb commands? I need this to be total transparent to tester i.e. tester should only have to execute a 'get logs' command after doing tests.

Comment: Yes and no. The thing is plugin-based. So you write a plugin which is activated at a certain breakpoint and then you can interact in a automated way with the gdb. 

You can find what's currently implemented [here](https://github.com/mw-sc/mw.gdb-runner#frame)

I use it mainly to stub the syscalls on on a none-eabi controller and to get the data that way. But if you want to extend that, I'd be more than happy to accept PRs and help you. Just write me a mail.